# Is it "childs" or "child's"

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

I am making a website to manage homework for students, parents and teachers.

Anyway, I want the grammar to be correct and was wondering what would be the correct way to say this:

```
All of your child's homework is complete.
```

I don't know whether this is `childs` or not, I am referring to a single child in this sentence by the way. Not multiple.

Or am I making this sentence wrong anyway and there is a better way, because it sounds wierd.

Comment: Plural of 'child' is 'children', not *childs*, so it's *child's*.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul ok thanks, I thought it was that but it sounded weird when I read it aloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Child's" is the "possessive" for "child".

"All of your child's homework is complete" means that the homework belonging to your child is complete.

And note that if you have more than one child, the plural is "children", not "childs", and the sentence would be "All of your children's homework is complete."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `child's` is correct.

The possessive form of `child` is `child's`.